# ImageMagick Invalid Parameter

Tags: java, aem, processbuilder, imagemagick-convert

I am using process command to run imagemagic as below :

```
try {
            System.out.println(" Image is Processing :: " + assetDetails.getName() + "Original Size :: " + assetDetails.getSize());
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("convert", "-quality", "85%", assetDetails.getAssetNode().getPath(), assetDetails.getAssetNode().getPath());
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

            Process p = pb.start();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            System.out.println(p.waitFor());
            session.save();

        } catch (final IOException | RepositoryException | InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am getting an error : `Invalid Parameter - 85%` and image is not compressing. However, If I run the same command from local. It execute successfully.

```
C:\Users\vdhim6\Desktop\imgcompression>convert -quality 85% source.jpg destination.jpg

C:\Users\vdhim6\Desktop\imgcompression>
```

Comment: Use `-quality` same as command line, not `-Quality`

Comment: tried with small q as well. Same error.

Comment: Is this some Windows-y environment that goes through Microsoft's CMD.EXE shell type of thing? If so, you probably need to double the percent signs (`85%%`) or add a caret to escape it (`85^%`).

Comment: We need to set the full path of convert.exe in order to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Should provide the full path of convert.exe as follows :

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.9.9-Q16\\convert.exe", "-quality", "85%", assetDetails.getAssetNode().getPath(), assetDetails.getAssetNode().getPath());
```

Comment: If you install v7 of ImageMagick you could avoid these issues by using `magick` in place of `convert`...